# Error HTTP 404.0 - No encontrado - IIS

Tags: c#, angularjs, mvc

Cuando hago una petición *AJAX*, lo raro es que cuando lo ejecuto localmente funciona perfectamente pero cuando lo subo al *IIS* me tira el siguiente error.

> Error HTTP 404.0 - No encontrado
>
> Detalles:
>
> Módulo: IIS Web Core
> Notificación: MapRequestHandler
> Controlador: StaticFile
> Código de error: 0x80070002
> Ruta: http://15.15.1.159:80
> Ruta física: C:\Users\admwebsrvs\Documents\webservices\Home\GetUsers
> Método de inicio de sesión: Anonymous
> Usuario de inicio de sesión: Anonymous

**RouteConfig.cs**:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

**HomeController.cs**:

```
[HttpGet]
public String GetUsers()
{
    List<User> lista = new List<User>();

    var usersArray = GetUserFromFile(WITH_ID);

    if (usersArray == null)
        return "No se ha podido recuperar la información del servidor";
        
    return usersArray.ToString();
}
```

Petición *AJAX*:

```
function loadTable(){

    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        onLoader();

        $http.get('../Home/GetUsers').then(callbackUsers);

        function callbackUsers(result) {
            defer.resolve(result.data);
            $scope.users = result.data;

            offLoader();
        }
        return defer.promise;

    }).withBootstrap()
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      .withOption('createdRow', createdRow);

    vm.dtColumns = [
    
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstname').withTitle('Nombre'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastname').withTitle('Apellido'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('email').withTitle('Correo'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('username').withTitle('Usuario de Red'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('Id').notVisible(),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
            .renderWith(actionsHtml)
    ];
}
```

Comment: si anda local y no web, es que hay un problema de accesos y rutas.. chequea todo eso de alguna forma.

Comment: Hola @user33963, intenta poniendo `$http.get('/Home/GetUsers').then(callbackUsers);` es posible que los puntos estén ocasionando que no encuentre la ruta deseada

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,
Localmente decís usando el iisexpress? Revisa desde las propiedades del proyecto web, en que uri está creado tu sitio en iis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]